# Bad performance when using `str.indexof` with `int2bv`

Tags: z3, smt

I am trying to constrain a bitvector to be equal to the index of a null byte in a string. However, I am getting performance issues with `int2bv`.

As a simple example of the issue, this problem (without `int2bv`) solves instantly:

```
; Solve time: 0m0.065s
(declare-const s String)
(declare-const len Int)
(assert (= (str.indexof s "\00") len))
(assert (>= len 256)) ; 0x100
(assert (<= len 4095)) ; 0xFFF
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

On the other hand, the "same" problem (it allows strictly more solutions) using `int2bv` takes almost 2 minutes:

```
; Solve time: 1m54.861s
(declare-const s String)
(declare-const len Int)
(assert (= (str.indexof s "\00") len))
(assert (>= len 0))
(assert (not (= (bvand ((_ int2bv 12) len) #xF00) #x000)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Is there a better way to encode this kind of bitvector string length operation in z3? [These slides](http://smt-workshop.cs.uiowa.edu/2016/slides/berzish.pdf) on z3strBV claim to have better support, but their extensions don't seem to be implemented in the standard z3 distribution.

I am using z3 version 4.8.0 - 64 bit and running with `smt.string_solver=z3str3`.

Comment: You're really at the mercy of the heuristics here. I'm sure if you asserted the disjunction that `len` converted to a 12-bit BV and is equal to one of `256`, `257` ... `4095` would be solved quickly. Would you consider a faithful translation? It's really hard to predict performance when you combine theories in arbitrary ways, unfortunately.

Comment: @alias That would be faithful, but of course a huge encoding. I did find that if I do `(set-option :smt.str.use_binary_search true)` the solve time for the long one drops to under 2 seconds!

Comment: Not sure why the default setting is false for that, it's a godsend!

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that option. The problem is, of course, you can always concoct a program where the binary-search performs horribly while the regular solver can get really quickly. You can try using "tactics," and run them in parallel perhaps. See here for the tactic language; http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~msagiv/courses/asv/z3py/strategies-examples.htm (It's in Python, but you can express similar things using the SMTLib interface as well.)

Comment: @alias That's an interesting approach, thanks!

Comment: Looks like the option you found does the trick. You can answer your own question and accept it, that way it'll be more easily accessible to others on stack-overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through trial and error I found that the option `smt.str.use_binary_search=true` drops the solve time for the second problem to under 2 seconds! Not sure why the default value for this option is false, though.